# Eclipse hangs during creation of cloud endpoints

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using latest google plugin for eclipse (1.7.5) but when ever I try to create an app engine connected android project, Eclipse hangs up during "Generation of cloud endpoint Library"

Same is the case when I create a google app engine project and then manually create endpoints.

Is there any workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it lock up your machine, or just take a long time (how long are you waiting?) Any status updates in the Eclipse logs?

Comment: For me, it cab 'appear' to hang for a while, but eventually comes back.  When it returns you should check the error log.

Comment: It doesn't lock up my machine ! And yes now I have figured out that eventually it does come back but it takes a lot of time about 5-10 min .

Comment: It's downloading a set of libraries. How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If you, can you please provide the solution? If not, can you please add more details about the Eclipse logs and the speed of your connection?